# I cleaned scuffs off shiny finished leather shoes with the wrong kind of toothpaste

Tags: shoes, color

I cleaned scuff marks off my high shine finished leather shoes with gel toothpaste, and now those areas are faded and no longer shiny. How can I restore color to them without having to use a color restore product? They are dark tan Clarks brand loafers that I cannot soak in any way. And none of the polishes or any other color restore products match. I fear that I will mess them up even further.

Answer (score 2):

Toothpaste contains an abrasive, and leather is much softer than your teeth.

If you can't match the colour, use **clear** or **neutral** shoe polish.
If you scuff the shoes again, only use a cleaning product intended for shoes.

Comment: There isn't a "right kind of toothpaste" for cleaning shoes.